# Is it possible to distinguish between data not found and columns is null in mybatis/hibernate

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, mybatis

Is it possible to distinguish between data not found and columns is null in mybatis/hibernate?

**Table:**

```
example {
  id,
  string,
  date,
  number,
  ...
}
```

**SQL:**

```
select string,date,number from example where id = #{id}
```

**Example for MySQL:**
[image: example of mysql]

In the above image, we can see the difference between data exists(id = 1, but other columns value is null) and data not exists(id = 2). Can I distinguish between these two cases when I use mybatis/hibernate?

Comment: With MyBatis, it is possible by enabling `returnInstanceForEmptyRow` in the config. See the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html).

Comment: @ave Oh, I missed the doc and misunderstood the meaning of `returnInstanceForEmptyRow`.